# Sending screen resolution via a form

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms, screen-resolution

I've got it sending the user agent already:

```
<input type='hidden' name='user-agent' value='<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>'/><input type="submit" value="Send User Agent" />
```

I've done my research and there is some code out there that sadly doesn't work. It's other people with problems asking for help themselves.

How can I go about sending screen resolutions using php forms?

Comment: Back to your respective corners, gentlemen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will not get the screen resolution from the server IMHO... you could let the form be rendered and then use javascript to update a form input with the correct information

HTML

```
<input id="browser-resolution" type="hidden" name="resolution" value="">
```

and afterwards as a script

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('browser-resolution').value = screen.width + "x" + screen.height;
</script>
```

EDIT: added [fiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/NEWSe/)

Comment: I didn't realise I need the script in the body as opposed to the head :) Works fine now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to fill in the screen resolution via JavaScript and then send it. This is not a safe method, since anyone who wanted to could change the value in the hidden field... But it will work:

```
// Fill in forms with screen resolution (jQuery)
$('#screenWidth').val(screen.width);
$('#screenHeight').val(screen.height);
```

And simply use a couple of hidden fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="screenWidth" id="screenWidth"/>
<input type="hidden" name="screenHeight" id="screenHeight"/>
```

Comment: thank you - I've already tried this and I cannot get it to work. Also in regards to it not being safe only a select few will use it to benefit themselves anyway so they won't be messing around with it.

Comment: Do you have jQuery loaded? The screen object works in every browser since Navigator 4.0x and Internet Explorer 4.0x

Comment: It doesn't work in Google Chrome, let me see if it works in Firefox.

Comment: Check for jQuery, the screen object works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE..., if you don't use jQuery just access the value directly: document.getElementById("screenWidth").value = screen.width;

Comment: I've got the jquery library called in the head - <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Name: 

screenWidth: 

screenHeight: 

Email: 

Nope. Here is the website - http://channel944.com/useragent.php

Comment: For just javascript, see this page. no need to load a large library like jQuery for a simple task http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html

Answer (score 1):

The previous example should work:

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('debug').value = screen.width + 'x' + screen.height;
```

Are you getting any errors? Which browser are you using? OS?

Comment: And also make sure that your javascript is executed when the dom is already loaded so that you can actually find the 'debug' field that I am using in this example.

Comment: OK stupid question but do you have an element with id set to debug? And if yes, then do you execute the Javascript on dom load?

Comment: I do, I have <input id="debug" type="hidden" name="resolution" value="">. How do I execute the javascript on dom load?

Comment: I believe I've now executed the javascript on dom load using:

<script>
window.onload = function (){
document.getElementById('debug').value = screen.width + 'x' + screen.height;
}
</script>

Still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

As other people have said, the `screen` object works. Just saying "It doesn't work" doesn't help with finding the problem out. If you have jQuery correctly loaded, it will just work.

```
screen.width + "x" + screen.height
```

This returns "1280x1024" in my case.

See http://jsfiddle.net/KVQM4/ for an example of it working. If you can create something similar to show how it doesn't work, or give us a bit more information as to the error.

Comment: But this doesn't allow me to send it using a php form. When I send it using php forms it doesn't work and I haven't a clue why. I did include a direct link to the website, here it is again - http://channel944.com/useragent.php