# Submit user screen resolution in Contact Form 7

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, contacts, contact-form-7

I want to see the specific Contact Form 7 submissions that are sent using mobile devices. So I was wondering how to automatically input screen resolution information in contact form 7 submission.

I tried to use the following method but had no luck.
[Sending screen resolution via a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296772/sending-screen-resolution-via-a-form)

Will really appreciate your kind suggestions.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2242086/how-to-detect-the-screen-resolution-with-javascript Once you have the resolution, the form is easy. Do note that adding JS to wordpress also needs some setup, but there's other tutorials/questions for that.

Comment: I am not quite sure how it would work. How to parse the script data to CF7 mail shortcode?

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field in CF7 and give it an ID:

```
<input type="hidden" id="drez" val=""/>
```

Then add this to your javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wRez = $(window).width()+'x'+$(window).height();
       $("input#drez").val(wRez);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips. But did you try it? I can enter it in the form tab of CF7, but what shortcode shall I be using under the Mail tab?